# Calculate bedframe strength

Tags: bedroom

This is the bed frame that I have build now, the part in red is something I have created but did not dare to attach it yet.

[image]

I have used Spruce wood for everything, and the long side of the frame is attached to the short side via dowels and two large wood screws on each side.

Now my question is about the load on the frame that I created (see the arrow pointing to the rectangular shaped object).

My feeling says that I need to add extra support to that frame, and that I need to add extra support between the three components as well to create a stable frame.
However, to gain trust in my schema I would like to calculate some stresses, or deflections that the beams will undergo due to the static load and dynamic load of me and my partner.

I have found some equations to calculate some part of the load, but I dont think this will capture all the stresses. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

PS: Thanks for the tips and the comments guys, I hope the question is now better suited for this forum.

Comment: As it's formulated, this question isn't really suitable for a home improvement network. While there are some engineering-minded folks around, this type of math isn't really what we do here. Instead, describe your design or post a diagram and we can discuss viability based on real-world experience.

Comment: Check the value for Young's Modulus.  It looks way too low, and the units are wrong.  Values I'm finding are around 10 GPa - 10,000,000,000 N/m2.

Comment: I think I indeed mixed up the Youngs Modulus. And will add more pictures of my current situation

Comment: I have no idea what it is that you're showing here. Can you do a 3D hand-drawn sketch, or show a comparable existing structure/product somewhere? "Bedframe" is a term with highly localized meaning, it will mean completely different things depending on who you ask. When computing structures you always need to describe how the structure will be loaded, and how it's supported. Without this information, your question is not answerable. And I have built and calculated a few bedframes for my own use - I still have no idea what you want, how it's put together, etc. All you show is a flat lattice.

Comment: Maybe make a cardboard scale model first, hot-glue it together to resemble what you want, use a piece of foam/styrofoam for the mattress, and show your intentions.